# Local Temporary Tables not dropped with "drop table"

Tags: sql-server

I have some local temporary tables that I can't drop them, would you know if there is any way to drop them?

[image]

Example:
[image]

It's like they don't exist for me

Comment: Because they are not yours - tempdb is used by all users and various processes; why do you want to drop them?

Comment: Because of the history, I don't want to keep them there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are the internal names given to table variables or [currently idle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13412/3690) [cached temporary tables](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-performance/sql-server-temporary-object-caching) for stored procedures.

You can't drop them with `DROP TABLE`.

For table variables/temp tables that are cached as part of an execution plan context then evicting the plan from the cache will also drop the table but you shouldn't do this.

Comment: I understand, so there is no way to remove these tables, only the service remains in the case so that the cache is removed

Comment: @arodrber - if they are a table variable that belongs to another session then the only way to remove them would be to kill the session. Unlikely though as they are 5 days old. Probably they are just cached temporary objects that are there as an optimisation. And they will be tiny ( one empty data page, and one IAM page) and not worth worrying out

Comment: No probs, ICYMI You can read more about temp object caching here https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-performance/sql-server-temporary-object-caching